# mapping data with a spike to a heat map

Tags: visualization, data-management

I have the following dataset that I need to display on the heat map:

[30, 15, 66, 7, 9999, 78, 42, 132]

So if I map the values to the color scale using a linear function I only see the spike while the rest of the values I cannot tell apart because the difference between them is insignificant in the scale of that spike.

I tried a log function but it didn't get a good looking picture either.

I don't care about accurate correspondence between the value and the color intensity.

Is there a way to map the values to the color scale so that the difference between all values was visible? Can I mitigate that spike somehow? I am rather asking about established approaches or algorithms addressing problems like this.

Comment: What language or data visualization tool are you using?

Comment: JavaScript and AmMaps controls

Comment: It doesn't look like you can control the gradient with ammaps but I haven't used it. You could probably filter your data and then do drill down maps to get an overlay effect.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways of handling outliers, as well as answers to similar questions here already. I would recommend taking a look at

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811866/ggplot2-color-scale-over-affected-by-outliers
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Working_with_outliers

The first deals with this problem in R. Taking the approach of graphing the non-outliers with a heatmap, then overlaying the outliers and annotating the legend to describe that this is what was done.

The second contains links to general solutions and approaches to outliers.